# Php regex not matching properly

Tags: php, regex

Hellow guys am weak in regular expressions i need to match a string in regex by using the 
preg_match function in php .

I know how to use these function but am weak in regular expression ..

```
$something = "i live in india";
$new = preg_match(pattern, $something);
```

Here i just need to know the pattern or how to match "i love my india" in regex ?

Comment: Why? $something is already your match. What are you trying to achieve? Or better: What do you not want to be matched by your regex?

Comment: what you want actually need tutorial?

Comment: There is no dynamic part in your string. The pattern you need is just `i live in india`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Go learn: http://gskinner.com/RegExr

Comment: @UriY i need to match i live from the string

Comment: @SAarah I still don't understand. could you please give some examples of what the input strings can be and what you want to match in them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match **exactly** and **only** `i love my india` you should use a pattern like [`/i love my india/`](http://regexr.com?382qt).

But regular expressions tend to serve for *more complex cases*, and if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string, use `strpos()` or `strstr()` instead as they [will be faster](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Remember that `preg_match` [returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). If you want to know the matched results, use a third argument on the function call.

Answer (score -1):

@SAarah

Use the following code to match **i live** from the string  **i live in india**

```
$something = "i live in india";
$matches = array();

preg_match('/i\slive/i',$something,$matches);

//If the match is found it will print it
if ($matches) {
    echo $match[0];
}
```

You may look into detail of preg_match here http://pk1.php.net/preg_match